# Reflective pattern of numbers in rows and columns of html table using loops

Tags: php, loops, html-table, integer, palindrome

I'm stuck trying to use nested loops to make a reflective pattern from numbers.

I've already tried, but the output looks like this:

```
|0|1|2|
|0|1|2|
|0|1|2|
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
for ($row=1; $row <= 3; $row++) { 
    echo "<tr> \n";

    for ($col=1; $col <= 3; $col++) { 
        $p = $col-1;
        echo "<td>$p</td> \n";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

I expected this result:

```
|0|1|0|
|1|2|1|
|0|1|0|
```

Each columns' and rows' cell values must increment to a given amount then decrement to form a mirror / palindromic sequence.

Comment: just doing my homework to make this pattern from number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare the square root of the of the table cell count. In other words, if you want a 5-by-5 celled table (25 cells), declare `$size = 5`

Since your numbers are starting from zero, the highest integer displayed should be `$size - 1` -- I'll call that `$max`.

I support your nested loop design and variables are appropriately named `$row` and `$col`.

Inside of those loops, you merely need to make the distinction between your "counters" as being higher or lower than half of the `$max` value.  If it is higher than `$max / 2`, you subtract the "counter" (e.g. `$row` or `$col`) from `$max`.

By summing the two potentially adjusted "counters" and printing them within your inner loop, you generate the desired pattern (or at least the pattern I think you desire).  This solution will work for `$size` values from `0` and higher -- have a play with my demo link.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kdeFU))

```
$size = 5;
$max = $size - 1;
echo "<table>\n";
for ($row = 0; $row < $size; ++$row) {
    echo "\t<tr>";
    for ($col = 0; $col < $size; ++$col) {
        echo "<td>" . (($row >= $max / 2 ? $max - $row : $row) + ($col >= $max / 2 ? $max - $col : $col)) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achive that.

An easy way to do that is;

```
<?php
$baseNumber = 0;

echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
for ($row = 0; $row < 3; $row++) {
    echo "<tr>";

    if ($row % 2 !== 0) {
        $baseNumber++;
    } else {
        $baseNumber = 0;
    }

    for ($col = 0; $col < 3; $col++) {
        echo "<td>" . ($col % 2 === 0 ? $baseNumber : $baseNumber + 1) . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Your question has no explanation.  If you actually understand the question please improve your code-only answer.

Comment: My *answer. He asked for an solution, not an explanation.

Comment: Then you don't understand the _actual_ purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: Please do not go into a discussion. I am a member for more than 8 years. He can clearly see the solution itself on the code. Please do not make this weird.

Comment: If you have been here for 8 eight years, you should know better. (This looks like an answer from 8 years ago)  I hope this doesn't get weird too.

Comment: @mickmackusa are you here to help or are you here to be a highbrow? Mind your own business please.

Comment: The importance of adding an explanation is so that any future users who come across this question can also understand your solution and apply it to their particular needs.  So it's usually better to start with the assumption that the reader doesn't understand it as clearly as you may think.

Comment: I am here to help.  Always.  I even encouraged you to improve your answer.  You are the one refusing to explain your own solution -- I don't understand the resistance.  I am not singling you out.  See #3 in my profile -- I make a habit of asking volunteers to explain their answers because this simple act benefits StackOverflow and its researchers.

Comment: The answer is actually self explanatory. This is not resistance. I don't need to add any further explanation. I will if i find it needs. Clearly, you can answer with an explanation.

Comment: I will answer when the question is sufficiently clear.

Comment: _"The answer is actually self explanatory"_ - The answer is self explanatory if you know PHP well. If you don't (like the OP and many of SO's users), then it's not clear. Otherwise you could argue that _all_ code is self explanatory. There's a lot of people that have never used/seen/heard of modulus or ternary operators for example.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson he already gave us a code, and i have improved it. So i think he can see the difference right? Do i need to add a comment block and add an image that circled the difference with a red arrow?

Comment: Ask yourself why you are here.  If you are here to farm unicorn points, you gain more upvotes by posting fully explained answers.  If you are here to help people, fully explained answers are the best way to help people.  Again, I just don't understand your resistance to improve your answer.  No one is asking you to do anything extraordinary -- just  be a good volunteer and help properly.

Comment: The code the OP gave us showed us that they _didn't_ understand it properly. If they did, they wouldn't have done it like that to begin with. As I mentioned in my last comment, you're using modulus and ternary which many (most?) new developers don't have a clue about. So the next time they have a similar issue, they will need to come back here since they didn't learn anything new so they can figure it out themselves. Never assume that others have your knowledge or understanding.

Answer (score 0):

this code will do what you want just `call` the `patternGenerator` function with the number of distinct numbers you want for your example these numbers are 3 (0,1,2).

the idea in this code is to use two `for loops` one that starts from the minimum number to the maximum one and the other one that starts after the maximum number decreasing to the minimum.

for example: 
if `min = 0` and `max = 5`
the first `loop` will print 0,1,2,3,4,5
and the second will print 4,3,2,1,0
and that's it.

at first, I created a function that creates just on row called `rowGenerator` it takes `$min` and `$max` as `parameters` and prints one row
so if we want to print a row like this: `|0|1|0|` then we will call this function with `min = 0` and `max = 1` and 
if we want to print a row like this: `|1|2|1|` then we will call it with `min = 1` and `max = 2`.

```
function rowGenerator($min, $max)
{
    echo '<tr>';

    for($i = $min; $i<=$max;$i++)
        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';

    for($i = $max-1; $i>=$min;$i--)
        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';

    echo '</tr>';   
}
```

for now, we can print each row independently. now we want to print whole the table if we look at the calls we do for the `rowGenerator` function it will looks as follow:

(`min = 0`, `max = 1`),
(`min = 1`, `max = 2`) and
(`min = 0`, `max = 1`).
minimums are (0,1,0).
yes, it's the same pattern again. then we need two `loops` again one to start from `0` and increase the number until reach `1`  and the other one to loop from `0` to `0`.

and that's what happened in the `patternGenerator` function. when you call it with the number of distinct numbers the `function` just get the `min` that will always be 0 in your case and the `max`.

```
function patternGenerator($numberOfDistinct )
{
    echo "<table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'>";
    $min = 0;
    $max = $numberOfDistinct - 2;
    for($i = $min;$i<=$max; $i++)
    {
        rowGenerator($i,$i+1);
    }
    for($i = $max-1;$i>=$min;$i--)
    {
        rowGenerator($i,$i+1);
    }
    echo '</table>';

}
```

this is the output of calling `patternGenerator(3)`:

[image: result of calling patternGenerator(3)]

the output of calling `patternGenerator(5)`:

[image: result of calling patternGenerator(5)]

Comment: That may be true, but future researchers who visit this site deserve our very best efforts.  If you are feeling "used", you have the right to withhold/retract your solution.